# ext.js - can't apply XML data to a template

Tags: xml, model, extjs

I'm using ext.js to get data from an XML file and loop through the results to display them in a template, but it's not working. I can successfully loop through the results and log them to the console, but when I pass them on to the template, nothing gets displayed. Here's my code:

```
Ext.regModel('Work', {
    fields: ['title', 'thumb', 'video']
});

var workStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Work',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        //url : 'http://superfad.com/work/work_xml',
        url : 'lib/xml/work_xml.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'project'
        }
    }
});

t_work = new Ext.Component({
    cls:'t_work', title:'Work',
    title:'Work',
    scroll: 'vertical',
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="work">',
                    '<h3 class="work_title">{title}</h3>', //this doesn't work
                    '<div class="work_thumb">',
                        '<img src="{thumb}" alt="{title}"/>', //this doesn't work
                    '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    )
});

function loadWork(){
    workStore.load({
        callback: function(data) {
            var projects = data;
            t_work.update(projects)
            for (var i = 0, iln = projects.length; i < iln; i++){
                console.log(projects[i].get('title')) //this works
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share your xml?

Make sure your model fields have the exact same names as in the xml file, including uppercase letters. It might be that your model isn't set properly, i had this problem myself.
Also make sure that you don't have a root node in the xml file. If you do have a root node use the following (replace 'rootnode' with the name of the node):

```
var workStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Work',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        //url : 'http://superfad.com/work/work_xml',
        url : 'lib/xml/work_xml.xml',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'project',
            root: 'rootnode'
        }
    }
});
```